# Encontrar el segundo espacio en una cadena en SQL

Tags: sql

Estoy trabajando con nombres del tipo "Apellido 1°Nombre 2°Nombre" y necesito saber en qué posición se encuentra el segundo espacio, para así luego poder quedarme solo con el apellido y el 1°nombre.

Comment: ¿Y por qué no mejor separas los valores en diferentes campos?. Lo digo porque ese tipo de separaciones es fuente de muchos errores al por ejemplo fallar de reconocer apellidos compuestos

Comment: Necesito que queden juntos, porque luego los necesito para comparar nombres en distintas bases de datos

Comment: No, no necesitas que estén juntos, lo que mencionas es exactamente la razón por la cual necesitas que estén separados

Comment: y qué pasa cuando el nombre o apellido es compuesto?

Comment: mas alla de todos los comentarios, por favor mira [ask], [tour] y tambien es muy importante que aclares siempre la base de datos (disntintas bases de datos tienen distintas funciones)

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontre la solución, simplemente realice una función propia; la cual crea un ciclo, utilizando dos veces *charindex*

Answer (score 0):

La propuesta personal es primero pensar en todos las posibilidades; Carlos Muñoz hace cuestión sobre que pasa con "reconocer apellidos compuestos" por ejemplo:

- De La Torre

Si el usuario posee tal apellido "Pedro José De La Torre" te daría problemas en tu algoritmo al querer extraer solo el apellido y el primer nombre ya que la extracción quedaría algo como "DE LA".
A pesar de ello me parece interesante proponer una solución y pues bueno mi primera solución, es generar una columna a la tabla donde deberá imprimirse el numero de espacios en la cadena que estas buscando para distinguir entre apellidos compuestos y los normales de una sola palabra, para ello te recomiendo primero crear una función tal que asi:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CountSubStr](@str varchar(1000),@sub varchar(1000))
RETURNS int
BEGIN
    DECLARE @VECES  INT= len(@str);
    DECLARE @i      INT=1
    DECLARE @s2     varchar(100)=@str;
    DECLARE @s3     varchar(100);
    DECLARE @ESPACIOS INT=0;
    --
    WHILE(@i<@VECES+1)
        BEGIN
        set @s3=SUBSTRING(@s2,@i,1) 
        if (@s3=@sub) set @ESPACIOS=@ESPACIOS+1
        --
        set @i=@i+1
        END 
  RETURN @ESPACIOS
END
GO
```

DONDE: `@str` será el String total de la cadena del nombre completo y `@sub` será el substring que estas buscando y que será contado en la variable `@ESPACIOS`.

Despues de este proceso podrás saber exactamente o filtrar en función de cuantos espacios tienes por cada Nombre Completo.

Luego.. Cuando ya sepas todos los que poseen 3 espacios solo a ellos podrás aplicar una función CharIndex con la que podras conocer el valor de la posición de tu segundo espacio con el siguiente algoritmo:

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(100)='MORENO MARIO JOSÉ';
DECLARE @POSICION INT=0;
DECLARE @SUBSTR VARCHAR(100) = @STRING;
DECLARE @POSICIONRESULT INT=0;


        SET @POSICION=CHARINDEX(' ',@SUBSTR);
        SET @SUBSTR=SUBSTRING(@SUBSTR,@POSICION,LEN(@SUBSTR));  
        SET @POSICIONRESULT=@POSICION   
        SET @POSICION=CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(@SUBSTR)));
        SET @SUBSTR=SUBSTRING(@SUBSTR,@POSICION,LEN(@SUBSTR));      
        SET @POSICIONRESULT=@POSICIONRESULT+@POSICION


PRINT @POSICIONRESULT
```

Answer (score -1):

Este script funciona en mysql:

```
SELECT locate(' ',nombre,locate(' ',nombre) + 1) as pos,nombre FROM tabla
```

Con `locate` buscamos la primera aparición de una sub-cadena en una cadena desde un punto de inicio (el tercer parámetro de la función), lo que hacemos aquí es llamar dos veces a `locate`, la primera nos dirá la posición del primer espacio, y esto lo ingresamos como parámetro a la segunda llamada para iniciar la búsqueda desde el primer espacio + 1.

si no se suma el 1 siempre devolverá el valor del primer espacio.